# could not find driver laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, windows, visual-studio-code

I just started to using laravel. and at the moment to execute the command `php artisan migrate` in the terminal i get this error.

[image: Terminal error display]

I'm vs code editor in windows 10 OS
Thanks

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the PDO drivers. it also looks like you are running Xampp which should include these drivers, this is sometimes caused by having 2 versions of PHP installed and not configured correctly. Please share your phpinfo() or try re-installing Xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is displaying, because it cannot find the PHP PDO driver.

Check in your "**php.ini**" file, if the PDO driver is enabled and if the PDO help for your bank is also enabled.

Example:

```
extension = pdo_mysql
;extension = pdo_pgsql
```

"To enable, just remove **;** to the left of the extension name".